# how to make a PhoneStateListener for VoIP calls

Tags: android, voip

iam using a `PhoneStateListener` i want to listen if a VoIP call has been made from Viper or Skype or any thing like that, iam implementing listener to `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY` but it is not working write. here is my code

```
public class VoIPDetectionActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        TelephonyManager obj =  (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       PhoneStateListener listener1 = new PhoneStateListener(){    
       @Override
      public void onDataActivity (int direction){
          String stateString = "N/A";
          switch (direction) {
        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE:
          stateString = "Idle";
          break;
        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_IN:
          stateString = "Off Hook";
          break;
        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT:
          stateString = "Ringing";
          break;
        case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT:
            stateString = "Ringing";
            break;
          }
       }
       };



       // Register the listener with the telephony manager
       obj.listen(listener1, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY);
      }
```

iam geting the `TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE` but not the others, can any one help me with this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons that this might not work.  Most of the time Voip occurs over wifi, and the `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY` only works for cellular according to the documentation. Also, I'm not sure about Viper, but skype uses it's own Voip protocol to throw another wrench in the mix.

A possible solution is to poll the AudioManager for the communication mode.

Here's a link that shows someone setting this.

[How implement the VOIP application using android.net.rtp package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884713/how-implement-the-voip-application-using-android-net-rtp-package)