# How work with remote IP addresses for implement the application using android-net-rtp-package?

Tags: android, voip, rtp

Good day!

Wrote the application on the basis of this here [How implement the VOIP application using android.net.rtp package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884713/how-implement-the-voip-application-using-android-net-rtp-package)

When both phones in the same wi-fi network that all works (addresses like 192.168.1.44)But how to make the program work if the phones in different wi-fi networks or 3g?

Answer (score 1):

Think you would have to let the phones report their ip to a server, which then forwards any change in ip to the communicating phones.

Though, even with that in place, there are a whole lot of obstacles to overcome.

What if the phones are behind firewalls, or changing ip's often, should they pull the server all the time? If not and you would like to forward upon ip change you need to implement something Google Cloud Message and even with that, it can take up to 5 - 10 seconds before the ip update arrives. What happens in the mean time?

I was hoping I could redirect you to a SkypeKit API for android but i am not sure if they even have that yet, would have been a much easier and solid solution, I think.

I apologize for the somewhat bad news answer but I would think that it is a waste of time going down this road. Unless you find some sort of API that has handled most of the difficulties involved in such an application.